# Generalizing the ScaleTransform (WPF) when image is not aligned to x-y axes

Tags: wpf, linear-algebra, scaletransform, matrix-transform

My linear algebra is weak. WPF is a great system for Rendering different transformations upon an image. However, the standard ScaleTransform will only scale the image's along the x-y axes. When the edges have first been rotated, the result of applying the ScaleTransform will result in a skewed transformation (as shown below) since the edges are no longer aligned.

So, if I have an image that has undergone several different transforms with the result being shown by the WPF rendering system, how do I calculate the correct matrix transform to take the (final rotated image) and scale ***it along the axes of the rendered image?***
[image]

Any help or suggestions will be most appreciated.

TIA

(For the complete code, please see my previous question.)

Edit #1: To see the above effect:

1. Drop image onto Inkcavas.  -- no skewing seen.
2. Rotate image counterclockwise (to about 45deg) -- no skewing seen.
3. Make the image larger (about twice its prescaled size -- no skewing seen.
4. Rotate the image clockwise (about back to where it started) -- skewing is
   immediately seen during and after the rotation.

If step 3 is skipped, simple rotation -- no matter how many times done -- will not cause the skewing effect. Actually, this makes sense. The ScaleTransform preserves the distance from center from the edges of the image. If the image is at an angle, the x-y distance from the edges of the transform are no longer constant through the width and length of the rendered image. So the edges get appropriately scaled, but the angles are changed.

Here is the most relevant code:

```
private ImageResizing(Image image)
        {
            if (image == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("image");

           _image = image;
            TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();

            image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);  // All transforms will be based on the center of the rendered element.
            tg.Children.Add(image.RenderTransform);             // Keeps whatever transforms have already been applied.
            image.RenderTransform = tg; 
            _adorner = new MyImageAdorner(image);               // Create the adorner.

            InstallAdorner();                                   // Get the Adorner Layer and add the Adorner.
        }
```

Note: The image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5) is set to the center
of the rendered image. All transforms will be based on the center of the image at the time it is seem by the transform.

```
 public MyImageAdorner(UIElement adornedElement)
      : base(adornedElement)
    {
        visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);


        // Initialize the Movement and Rotation thumbs.
        BuildAdornerRotate(ref moveHandle, Cursors.SizeAll);
        BuildAdornerRotate(ref rotateHandle, Cursors.Hand);

        // Add handlers for move and rotate.
        moveHandle.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(moveHandle_DragDelta);
        moveHandle.DragCompleted += new DragCompletedEventHandler(moveHandle_DragCompleted);
        rotateHandle.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(rotateHandle_DragDelta);
        rotateHandle.DragCompleted += new DragCompletedEventHandler(rotateHandle_DragCompleted);


        // Initialize the Resizing (i.e., corner) thumbs with specialized cursors.
        BuildAdornerCorner(ref topLeft, Cursors.SizeNWSE);

        // Add handlers for resizing.
        topLeft.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(TopLeft_DragDelta);

        topLeft.DragCompleted += TopLeft_DragCompleted;

        // Put the outline border arround the image. The outline will be moved by the DragDelta's
        BorderTheImage();
    }

  #region [Rotate]
    /// <summary>
    /// Rotate the Adorner Outline about its center point. The Outline rotation will be applied to the image
    /// in the DragCompleted event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void rotateHandle_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the position of the mouse relative to the Thumb.  (All cooridnates in Render Space)
        Point pos = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

        // Render origin is set at center of the adorned element. (all coordinates are in rendering space).
        double CenterX = AdornedElement.RenderSize.Width / 2;
        double CenterY = AdornedElement.RenderSize.Height / 2;

        double deltaX = pos.X - CenterX;
        double deltaY = pos.Y - CenterY;

        double angle;
        if (deltaY.Equals(0))
        {
            if (!deltaX.Equals(0))
                angle = 90;
            else
                return;

        }
        else
        {
            double tan = deltaX / deltaY;
            angle = Math.Atan(tan);  angle = angle * 180 / Math.PI;
        }

        // If the mouse crosses the vertical center, 
        // find the complementary angle.
        if (deltaY > 0)
            angle = 180 - Math.Abs(angle);

        // Rotate left if the mouse moves left and right
        // if the mouse moves right.
        if (deltaX < 0)
            angle = -Math.Abs(angle);
        else
            angle = Math.Abs(angle);

        if (double.IsNaN(angle))
            return;

        // Apply the rotation to the outline.  All Transforms are set to Render Center.
        rotation.Angle = angle;
        rotation.CenterX = CenterX;
        rotation.CenterY = CenterY;
        outline.RenderTransform = rotation;
    }

    /// Rotates image to the same angle as outline arround the render origin.
    void rotateHandle_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get Rotation Angle from outline. All element rendering is set to rendering center.
        RotateTransform _rt = outline.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

        // Add RotateTransform to the adorned element.
        TransformGroup gT = AdornedElement.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;
        RotateTransform rT = new RotateTransform(_rt.Angle);
        gT.Children.Insert(0, rT);
        AdornedElement.RenderTransform = gT;

        outline.RenderTransform = Transform.Identity;  // clear transform from outline.
    }
    #endregion  //Rotate


 #region [TopLeft Corner
    // Top Left Corner is being dragged. Anchor is Bottom Right.
    void TopLeft_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        ScaleTransform sT = new ScaleTransform(1 - e.HorizontalChange / outline.ActualWidth, 1 - e.VerticalChange / outline.ActualHeight,
            outline.ActualWidth, outline.ActualHeight);

        outline.RenderTransform = sT;   // This will immediately show the new outline without changing the Image.
    }



    /// The resizing outline for the TopLeft is based on the bottom right-corner. The resizing transform for the
    /// element, however, is based on the render origin being in the center. Therefore, the Scale transform 
    /// received from the outling must be recalculated to have the same effect--only from the rendering center.
    /// 
    /// TopLeft_DragCompleted resize the element rendering.
    private void TopLeft_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get new scaling from the Outline.
        ScaleTransform _sT = outline.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform;
        scale.ScaleX *= _sT.ScaleX; scale.ScaleY *= _sT.ScaleY;

        Point Center = new Point(AdornedElement.RenderSize.Width/2, AdornedElement.RenderSize.Height/2);

        TransformGroup gT = AdornedElement.RenderTransform as TransformGroup;

        ScaleTransform sT = new ScaleTransform( _sT.ScaleX, _sT.ScaleY, Center.X, Center.Y);
        gT.Children.Insert(0, sT);

        AdornedElement.RenderTransform = gT;
        outline.RenderTransform = Transform.Identity;           // Clear outline transforms. (Same as null).
    }
    #endregion
```

Note: I am adding each new transform to the first of the children list. This makes calculations on the image easier.

Comment: I've created test WPF app where I placed an image with `RenderTransform` set as `<TransformGroup><RotateTransform Angle="45"/><ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/></TransformGroup>`. Image correctly rotated and scaled without skewing. Show how you are applying transformations.

Comment: @Maxim  The problem isn't in the first rotate and size transform. The skewing occurs, however, after the first size transform as been applied. Please see above edits. Thanks.

Comment: So if I'll put another one `RotateTransform` in my `TransformGroup` I'll see the skewing?

Comment: @Maxim  I don't know about it in the XAML (as you are doing), but I clearly seem to be getting it when done in code.:)  (I must be missing something).

Answer (score 2):

I could not find with Google or in text all the elements needed to answer this question completely. So, for all other newbies like my self, I will post this (very long) answer. (Editors and Gurus please feel free to correct).

A word toward setup. I have an inkcanvas onto which an image is dropped and added as a child of the inkcanvas. At the time of the drop, an adorner containing a Thumb on each corner for resizing, a Top-Middle thumb for rotating, and a middle thumb for translation is added for final positioning of the image. Along with a "outline" designed as a path element, the Thumbs and outline complete the Adorner and create a kind of wire frame around the adorned element.

There are multiple key points:

1. WPF first uses a layout pass to position elements within their parent container, followed by a rendering pass to arrange the element. Transforms can be applied to either or both the layout and rendering passes. However, it needs to be noted that the layout pass uses an x-y coordinate system with the origin on the top left of the parent, where as the rendering system inherently references the top left of the child element. If the layout position of the dropped element is not specifically defined, it will by default be added to the "origin" of the parent container.
2. The RenderTransform is by default a MatrixTransform but can be replaced by a TransformGroup. Using either or both of these allows for Matrices (in the MatrixTransform) or Transforms (in the TransformGroup) to be applied in any order. My preference was to use the MatrixTransforms to better see the relationship between scaling, rotation, and translation.
3. The rendering of the adorner follows the element it adorns. That is, the element's rendering will also be applied to the Adorner. This behavior can be overriden by use of

   public override GeneralTransform GetDesiredTransform(GeneralTransform transform)

As noted in the initial question, I had avoided using SetTop() and SetLeft() as they messed up my other matrices. In hindsight, the reason my matrices failed was because SetTop() and SetLeft() apparently work during the layout phase--so all my coordinates for rendering were off. (I was using a TransalateTransform to position the image upon drag-drop.) However, using SetTop() and SetLeft() apparently act during the Layout Phase. Using this greatly simplified the calculations needed for the Rendering Phase since all coordinates could refer to the image without regard to the position on the canvas.

```
private void IC_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        InkCanvas ic = sender as InkCanvas;

        // Setting InkCanvasEditingMode.None is necessary to capture DrawingLayer_MouseDown.
        ic.EditingMode = InkCanvasEditingMode.None;

        ImageInfo image_Info = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageInfo)) as ImageInfo;
        if (image_Info != null)
        {
            // Display enlarged image on ImageLayer
            // This is the expected format for the Uri:
            //      ImageLayer.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Female - Front.png", UriKind.Relative));
            // Source = new BitmapImage(image_Info.Uri);

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Width = image_Info.Width * 4;

            // Stretch.Uniform keeps the Aspect Ratio but totally screws up resizing the image.
            // Stretch.Fill allows for resizing the Image without keeping the Aspect Ratio.    
            image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(image_Info.Uri);

            // Position the drop. Note that SetLeft and SetTop are active during the Layout phase of the image drop and will
            // be applied before the Image hits its Rendering stage.
            Point position = e.GetPosition(ic);
            InkCanvas.SetLeft(image, position.X);
            InkCanvas.SetTop(image, position.Y);
            ic.Children.Add(image);
            ImageResizing imgResize = ImageResizing.Create(image);
        }
    }
```

Since I want to be able to resize the image from any direction, the image is set with Stretch.Fill. When Stretch.Uniform was used, the image appeared to first be resized then jump back to its initial size.

- Since I am using MatrixTransform, the order of the Matrices is important. So when applying the Matrices, for my use

  ```
     // Make new render transform. The Matrix order of multiplication is extremely important.
          // Scaling should be done first, followed by (skewing), rotation and translation -- in 
          // that order.
          MatrixTransform gT = new MatrixTransform
          {
              Matrix = sM * rM * tM
          };

          ele.RenderTransform = gT;
  ```

Scaling (sM), is performed before Rotation (rM). Translation is applied last. (C# does matrix multiplication from left to right).

In review of the matrices, it is apparent that the Rotation Matrix also involves skewing elements. (Which makes sense since apparently the RotationTransform is intended to keep the angles at the edges constant). Thus, the Rotation Matrix depends on the size of the image.

In my case, the reason scaling after rotation was causing skewing is because the Scaling transform multiplies the distance between points of the image and the x-y axes. So if the edge of the image is not of constant distance to the x-y axes, scaling will distort  (i.e., skew) the image.

Putting this together, results in the following method to resize the image:

```
Action<Matrix, Vector> DragCompleted = (growthMatrix, v) =>
        {
            var ele = AdornedElement;

            // Get the change vector.  Transform (i.e, Rotate) change vector into x-y axes.
            // The Horizontal and Vertical changes give the distance between the the current cursor position
            // and the Thumb.
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.Rotate(-AngleDeg);
            Vector v1 = v * m;

            // Calculate Growth Vector.
            var gv = v1 * growthMatrix;

            // Apply new scaling along the x-y axes to obtain the rendered size. 
            // Use the current Image size as the reference to calculate the new scaling factors.
            var scaleX = sM.M11; var scaleY = sM.M22;
            var W = ele.RenderSize.Width * scaleX; var H = ele.RenderSize.Height * scaleY;
            var sx = 1 + gv.X/ W; var sy = 1 + gv.Y / H;

            // Change ScalingTransform by applying the new scaling factors to the existing scaling transform.
            // Do not add offsets to the scaling transform matrix as they will be included in future scalings.
            // With RenderTransformOrigin set to the image center (0.5, 0.5), scalling occurs from the center out.
            // Move the new center of the new resized image to its correct position such that the image's thumb stays
            // underneath the cursor.
            sM.Scale(sx, sy);


            tM.Translate(v.X / 2, v.Y / 2);


            // New render transform. The order of the transform's is extremely important.
            MatrixTransform gT = new MatrixTransform
            {
                Matrix = sM * rM * tM
            };
            ele.RenderTransform = gT;
            outline.RenderTransform = Transform.Identity;  // clear this transform from the outline.

        };
```

Just to be clear, my "Growth Matrix" is defined in such a manner as to result in "Positive" growth as the cursor is moved away from the center of the image. For Example, the TopLeft corner will "grow" the image when moved to the left and up. Hence

growth matrix = new Matrix(-1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0) for top-left corner.

The last problem is that of correctly calculating the rotation center (i.e., I want to spin, not orbit). This becomes greatly simplified by using

```
  // All transforms will be based on the center of the rendered element.
        AdornedElement.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
```

Lastly, since I am scaling from a corner, the center of the image needs to be translated to keep the corner underneath the cursor.

Sorry for the length of this answer, but there is much to cover (and learn :) ). Hope this helps somebody.